# The function $(String) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saw an example [here](http://jsbin.com/eyeyu/edit#javascript,html) and checked how it works but i got an error - (See Title)

Do you know why?

This is the code (Its similar to the link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<!--

  Created using /
  Source can be edited via /eyeyu/edit

-->
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('td').click(function(){
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    alert('Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you get an error in the jsbin demo, or in your own page?

Comment: You seriously need to learn about cacheing function results in variables. Use `me = $(this)` and replace all further calls to `$(this)` with `me`. You'll use several times less processing power and contribute less to global warming! That was a joke, but the efficiency gain is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your code works just fine!**

The problem by all the tests performed may come by the absence of the jQuery library,
see the [live simulation link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10664248/10664248.html) and [print-screen](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10664248/10664248.jpg).

Also, this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/FECGY/)

---

**As a side note:**

- You are missing a closing tag for `tbody` and have the opening tag
  out of order:

**UPDATE YOUR HTML TO THIS**

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- Your script tag is missing the type:

**UPDATE YOUR TAG TO THIS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

**AND**

```
<script src="path_to_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

## EDITED :: To better consolidate this answer

1. [Link to live HTML file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10664248/10664248.html) working!
2. [Link to live HTML file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10664248/10664248_force_fail.html) without the jQuery loaded, thus causing the error!
3. Print-screen for those who don't want to follow the link:

[image]

**Note:**
As stated by **cliffs of insanity** on the comments, [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is not needed on this case since the jQuery code is located below the elements it selects!

Comment: The code doesn't need to be in `.ready()` because it is located below the elements it selects. Also, that wouldn't cause the error in the first place.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Plus the compiler screams: **The function ready(Function) is undefined**
Are there any libraries I need to include for them?

Comment: Are you including Jquery ? Use your browser inspector to check if jQuery is being loaded!

Comment: @digvijay, I've run some tests and all checked out, see the answer for specific details!